# How can I populate text boxes with values from a properties file?

Tags: java

I have an html page with a dropdown box and a text box.

When an option is clicked in the dropdown, the value from the .properties file must be populated in the text box using java or java script (no database).

My properties file:

```
 servers=Demo
 serversTolookfor=Links,name
 Demo_name=Demo Server
 Demo_Links=https://mobileapplication.gh:8080
```

server.html:

```html
<table class="edit" cellpadding="15"><tr>
    <td style="color: white;" >Server Name:</td> 
    <td align="right"><selectname="serverName" class="dropdown">
    <option value="Demo Server">Demo Server</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="left" style="color: white;" >Server Link:</td><td align="right"><input type="text" name="server"></td>  
   </tr>
     </table>
     <input type="Submit" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 0):

use place holder in your jsp(don't use html file ) file.

**Spring config**

```
<util:properties id="propertyConfigurer" 
                  location="classpath:yourPropertyFileClasspathHere "/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer" />
```

**jsp**

```
<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('propertyNameHere')" />
```

Comment: I am not using spring. Can you tell me how to do it in java dao class

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want like this:

config.properties content

```
#Crunchify Properties
user=Crunchify
company1=Google
company2=eBay
company3=Yahoo
```

CrunchifyReadConfigMain.java

```
package crunchify.com.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CrunchifyReadConfigMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CrunchifyGetPropertyValues properties = new CrunchifyGetPropertyValues();
        properties.getPropValues();
    }
}
```

CrunchifyGetPropertyValues.java

```
package crunchify.com.tutorial;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CrunchifyGetPropertyValues {

    public String getPropValues() throws IOException {

        String result = "";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "config.properties";

        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
        Date time = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // get the property value and print it out
        String user = prop.getProperty("user");
        String company1 = prop.getProperty("company1");
        String company2 = prop.getProperty("company2");
        String company3 = prop.getProperty("company3");

        result = "Company List = " + company1 + ", " + company2 + ", " + company3;
        System.out.println(result + "\nProgram Ran on " + time + " by user=" + user);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Company List = Google, eBay, Yahoo
Program Ran on Mon Feb 23 21:54:55 PDT 2015 by user=Crunchify
```

Comment: Yes. It is displaying output in console. How do I display this in my jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in normal jsp then use following code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Properties"%>

<%
    Properties property = null;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path of A.properties") ;
    property =new Properties();
    property.load(fis);
    String username = property.getProperty("username"); 
%>
```